# Amazon ElastiCache vs Ramfs in Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I am new to Amazon Web Services. I was reading about `Amazon ElastiCache` and wanted to clarify if it is like (may be more than that) using `RAM filesystem` in Linux where we use a portion of system memory as a file system. As I referred AWS documentation it says ElastiCache is a web service. Is it like an EC2 instance with few memory modules attached? I really want to understand how it exactly works.

Our company has decided to migrate our physical servers into AWS cloud. We use Apache web server and MySQL Database running in Linux. We provide a SaaS platform for e-mail marketing and event scheduling for our customers. There is usually a high web traffic to our website during 9am-5pm on weekdays. I would like to understand if we want to use ElastiCache service, how it will be configured in AWS.? We have planned two EC2 instances for our web server and an RDS instance for the database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic cache is simply managed Redis or Memcached. Depending which one you choose, you would use the client for the cache with your application.

How you would implement it depends on what kind of caching you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: so, is it like a bunch of memory modules that made available to an EC2 instance for fast data processing?

Comment: Its more of a simple database (also known as a key value store). If you have some piece of your application that requires some work to build, but changes infrequently, that would be a good candidate for caching. You can use a Read Through strategy to only build it when its not found in the cache.